# ffmpeg "steam" cbr gop

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, steam

It's about live video streaming to STEAM... with ffmpeg

I have this command

```
ffmpeg -re -i file-from-webcam.webm -deinterlace 
-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryfast 
-tune zerolatency -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -crf 18 
-r 30 -g 60  -vb 1369k -minrate 1369k -maxrate 1369 -ar 44100 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr" 
-vf "scale=1280:720" -profile:v main 
-f flv "rtmp://ingest-rtmp.broadcast.steamcontent.com/app/steam_...."
```

but after a few seconds, the stream stops and the log of steam says

```
    Make sure your upload key-frame interval is set to 2 seconds 
and use constant bitrate (CBR). 
Limit your encoders group of picture (GOP) to at most two times your framerate.
```

but I do have `-x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr"` and  `-r 30 -g 60` framerate 30 GOP 60...

Is there something wrong in the ffmpeg command ?
Or is it linux server related ?

**** The SAME ffmpeg command work very nicely in youtube, twitter, twitch, dlive, facebook, etc...

so what I'm I missing to get it work for steam ?

Comment: 1) Show the **complete** log from the command. 2) `-maxrate 1369` is missing the `k`. 3) Why did you add `-strict -2`?

Comment: @llogan I fixed the command and now working `ffmpeg -re -i file.webm -deinterlace -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryfast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -crf 18 -r 30 -g 60  -vb 1369k -minrate 1369k -maxrate 1369k -ar 44100 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr" -vf "scale=1280:720" -profile:v main -f flv "rtmp://ingest-rtmp.broadcast.steamcontent.com/app/___key___"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -re -i file.webm -deinterlace -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -r 30 -g 60 -vb 1369k -minrate 1369k -maxrate 1369k -bufsize 2730k -ar 44100 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr" -vf "scale=1280:720,format=yuv420p" -profile:v main -f flv "rtmp://ingest-rtmp.broadcast.steamcontent.com/app/___key___"
```

- `-crf` and `-b:v`/`-vb` are mutually exclusive. It's likely your `-vb` was being ignored. Since you want a specific bitrate remove `-crf`.
- `-maxrate 1369` was missing the `k`.
- Add `-bufsize`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Encoding for Streaming Sites](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites#a-bufsize).
- No need for `-strict -2`. Users always add that without knowing why. (It was for the old AAC encoder before 2015.)
- Make sure your input has audio. Some sites like YouTube require audio. If it does not have audio use the [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) filter to generate silent audio.